# How to see which sites use my installed plugins (wordpress multisite)

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin, maintenance

How can I (easily) determine which of my wordpress sites are using a given plugin, on a Wordpress Multisite install?

Let's say I have 1,000 wordpress sites on a Wordpress Multisite install. I have 100 plugins.

For each plugin, I want to list all of the sites that are using that plugin.

In the GUI, I can only see how this can be done in about 1 million clicks. Is there a query I can run against the DB (and maybe cleanup with bash/awk/etc) that will automatically

1. Get all of the plugins installed
2. For each plugin, list all of the sites that use that plugin (by `site-id` is fine)

What's a fast way to determine all of the sites that use each of my installed plugins on Wordpress Multisite?

Comment: are you comfortable using WP CLI? If so there may be CLI based solutions here that don't require additional PHP/SQL

Comment: `wp-cli` is definitely a valid answer to this question. However, for this server, I can only use software that can be installed from a secure package manager with cryptographically signed manifests (which `apt` provides but composer, curl, git, brew, etc do not provide)

Comment: So uploading or downloading `wp-cli.phar` as the wp cli homepage says in that environment is not an option? Even then nothing prevents you downloading the data and running WP CLI locally, and WP CLI may be a hard requirement as you mentioned 1k+ sites ( and ignoring that files and commits in git are all managed using a cryptographic hash chain )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses `wp-cli` and will iterate through all plugins and it will print all sites that use each of those plugins.

```
sites=$(wp --quiet site list --field=url 2> /dev/null)
plugins=$(wp --quiet plugin list --field=name 2> /dev/null)
for plugin in $plugins; do
   echo $plugin;

   for url in $sites; do
      wp --quiet plugin is-active "${plugin}" --url="${url}" --network 2> /dev/null
      if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then

         echo -e "\t${url}"

      fi
   done
    
done
```

Credit to @tom-j-nowell as the above code is a modified version of his answer, but this also loops through plugins.

Comment: Why would you redirect all error output `2> /dev/null`? You should check of there are actually valid errors and display them in case.

Comment: Because there are invalid errors :) My server has some hardening that makes `wp-cli` spew out a *ton* of "errors" to stderr that make the output unreadable. Honestly, nobody should enable `ini_set()`; it defeats the purpose of hardening PHP at all :D

Comment: Well, this make this a very specific answer for yourself. Not something I would recommend people to copy and use like this. So wp-cli does not need `ini_set` but produces errors if its disabled?

Comment: It prints a ton of (non-critical) errors on any basic hardening. So this cleans it up for anyone (not just me) who follows basic PHP security best-practices

Comment: This will actually only print plugins which are NETWORK active (That's what the --network flag does). If you remove that flag, this code does indeed loop through each site and each plugin and check to see if that plugin is active on the given site. With the --network flag, it will only report on plugins that are active network-wide.

Answer (score 2):

You can list the sites a plugin has been activated on in the shell using WP CLI:

```sh
sites=$(wp site list --field=url)
for url in $sites; do
    if wp plugin is-active "YOURPLUGINNAME" --url="${url}" --network; then
        echo "${url}"
    fi
done
```

It will print out the URL of each site on its own line that has that plugin activated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not print the site if a plugin is enabled network-wide.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield that was never mentioned in the original post, my answer tries to list the active plugins on a site as your question requested, and if a plugin is network activated then it is not activated on those sites (but gets loaded anyway). Remember, I'm not trying to give you the answer you want, _I'm trying to answer the question you asked._ If there are things you expect that aren't said in your question, you have to say them. Listing plugins activated network wide requires a separate and fundamentally different answer ( aka just list all sites )

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding `--network` as instructed by the official WP CLI docs for the `plugin is-active` command: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/is-active/, but I would note this was not a part of the original question

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon an extension to WP-CLI that organizes the urls for each plugin queried, on [Github](https://github.com/iandunn/wp-cli-plugin-active-on-sites).

So I modified the solution by @michael-altfield to get better results:

```
plugins=$(wp --quiet plugin list --field=name 2> /dev/null)
# List all plugins first
printf "${plugins}\n\n"
for plugin in $plugins; do
   wp plugin active-on-sites "${plugin}"
done
```

Comment: Looks good, although this prints network activated plugins at the top of the list whereas it looks like the OP wanted each individual site listed for network-activated plugins (not sure why :-/ )

Comment: Well, the script will give a warning like, `Warning: woocommerce is network-activated.` in the terminal, so that it doesn't have to list all 1000 sites (chuckles)..